# Converting a seq[char] to string

Tags: nim-lang

I'm in a situation where I have a `seq[char]`, like so:

```nim
import sequtils
var s: seq[char] = toSeq("abc".items)
```

What's the best way to convert `s` back into a string (i.e. `"abc"`)? Stringifying with `$` seems to give `"@[a, b, c]"`, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most efficient way is to write a procedure of your own.

```
import sequtils
var s = toSeq("abc".items)

proc toString(str: seq[char]): string =
  result = newStringOfCap(len(str))
  for ch in str:
    add(result, ch)

echo toString(s)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import sequtils, strutils
var s: seq[char] = toSeq("abc".items)
echo(s.mapIt(string, $it).join)
```

Join is only for `seq[string]`, so you'll have to map it to strings first.

Comment: `mapIt` is now deprecated in favor of `applyIt`: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/3372/files

Comment: `mapIt` still works for this, but I don't think you need to type:
https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2IPE

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using a cast:

```
var s: seq[char] = @['A', 'b', 'C']
var t: string = cast[string](s)
# below to show that everything (also resizing) still works:
echo t
t.add('d')
doAssert t.len == 4
echo t
for x in 1..100:
  t.add('x')
echo t.len
echo t
```

Comment: a string is not binary equivalent to a seq[char], it contains an extra null byte, for compatibility with cstring

Comment: This seems to work, but be careful of casting. I made the mistake of doing `cast[string](['x'])` which segfaults, because I left out the `@` to convert an array to a seq.